# Why does Transmission BitTorrent client say "could not connect to tracker"?

Tags: 11.10, vpn, downloads, bittorrent, transmission

I recently cannot download anything via transmission and the download process remains idle("downloading from 0 of 0 connected peers").
Going through properties> trackers, I see "could not connect to tracker" or "tracker gave HTTP respond 404" messages in red.

I also use a VPN connection and I didn't have this problem on 11.04.

Is there a way to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can firewall problem?!

Comment: pardon? could you explain more?

Comment: you can not download any torrent file, right?

Comment: Yes, as I explained it doesn't start and remains idle.

Comment: As it stands, this answer is not very useful. If you can add some detail, that would be much appreciated. I'm going to flag it as "Not an answer" for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed "Vuze" and all the torrents downloaded. It had something to do with connecting to peers.

Follow the full discussion [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1733/conversation/why-does-transmission-bittorrent-client-say-could-not-connect-to-tracker).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a broken torrent file. Delete any active torrents and re-download them. See if the problem persists.

Comment: I deleted all torrents and tested 3 torrent movies but the problem is still there!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: not really, should i?

Comment: I would at least try it. Or download a diffrent bittorrrent application.

Answer (score 1):

Click on *torrent* (in bitcomet), and choose *updade tracker*. This solved my problem.

Comment: or for the command-line interface transmission-remote, use the option --reannounce

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when i first downloaded 10.10 so i had to download another bittorrent application since I was not able to fix this problem. But you can try to let it through the firewall manually.

In summary, you can:

- Go to your router's setup page and set up manual port forwarding for bittorrent on your machine.
- If that doesn't work, try using some bittorrent application *other than* Transmission, such as [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php).